# How to include autoload in module in drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, composer-php

I want to use `aws-sdk` for php client in a custom module of drupal. I need to include `vendor/autoload.php` in module. But when I include it, it gives me error. I have tried to include many ways but did not get success. I added it as:

`require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';` at the top of the file of `.module` file. Then the website gets crashed. Please could you tell how I should use `require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';`

Comment: You need to define a namespace to your module

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about how drupal handles autoloading of external php modules. But with the experience of working with frameworks like laravel, cakephp and with composer, I'm sure that the target file which is index.php which routes to a number of different controllers in root directory already includes vendor/autoload.php. If it does not include, add the require statement which points to autoload.php relative to index.php or absolute path.  Then using `namespaces` in php, you can use external php modules which are then autoloaded.

```
require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php'; // Incase vendor directory is in same level as index.php file
require dirname(__DIR__).'/vendor/autoload.php'; // Incase vendor directory is in parent level as index.php file
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know without the actual error message. If you're getting a white screen you need to enable display of full errors (`admin/config/development/logging`) so you can see what's actually going on and if the classes you're relying on aren't being included in the first place, or there's some sort of conflict (remember also to clear the cache after changing anything significant).

Here's how I've gone about adding 3rd party packages in custom D7 modules:

- generate a composer.json file that installs it in `vendor/`
- require `vendor/autoload.php` from `[modulename].module`

In detail:

- change to module directory
- run `composer init`
- follow prompts (it'll ask "Would you like to define your dependencies interactively" - choose yes then you can search by name)
- use `drupal-module` for type
- you can use "proprietary" for license if you don't want anyone else to use your code, this the composer.json validate cleanly (`composer validate`)
- When finished you should have a vendor directory that includes an `autoload.php` file and `/composer` directory. "Require" this from your `.module` file, e.g.:

`require 'vendor/autoload.php';`

- `drush cc all`

You should now be able to use your code.

---

Note there's a Drupal module called [xautoload](https://www.drupal.org/project/xautoload) - (in my opinion) overkill for this.

I had wondered if a simple `files[] =`  line for the `autoload.php` in `[modulename].info` would work - it doesn't, regardless of order.